# Loop over maps and assign value to local - Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to pass the values s3 name and create_user into local block in main.tf so that both of them have the value in list and then I am passing list_of_bucket in local block in module s3 to create the buckets and looping of user_to_create in module s3_user to create the user if the boolean is set to true. All of these values are passed to variable.tf and then to main.tf

dev.tfvars

```
wea-nonprod = {
     
    services = {
     
      s3 = [
        sthree = {
          create_user = true,
        }
        sfour = {
          create_user = true,
        }
        sfive = {
          create_user = true,
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

variable.tf

```
variable "s3_buckets" {
  type = list(map)
}
```

main.tf

```
locals { 
  users_to_create = ""
  list_of_buckets = ""
}

module "s3" {
  source = "../../s3"
  name = join("-", [var.name_prefix, "s3"])    
  tags = merge(var.tags, {Name = join("-", [var.name_prefix, "s3"])})
  buckets = list_of_buckets
  sse_algorithm = "AES256"
  access_log_bucket_name = var.access_log_bucket_name
}

module "s3_user" {
  for_each = local.users_to_create 
  source = "./service-s3-bucket-user"
  name = join("-", [var.name_prefix, each.key])
  tags = var.tags
  bucket_arn = module.s3.bucket_arns[each.key]
  depends_on = [module.s3]
}
```

Comment: Please don't make duplicate questions. There is already answer posted. If it does not work, please comment on it and explain what's wrong, so that the person answering could potentially amend it.

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate over your `wea-nonprod` map:

```
locals { 
  users_to_create = [ for name in var.wea-nonprod.services.s3 if name.create_user == true ]
  list_of_buckets = [ for bucket in var.wea-nonprod.services.s3 ]
}
```

And a few changes to your module blocks:

```
module "s3" {
  source                 = "../../s3"
  name                   = "${var.name_prefix}-s3"
  tags                   = merge(var.tags, { Name = "${var.name_prefix}-s3" })
  buckets                = local.list_of_buckets
  sse_algorithm          = "AES256"
  access_log_bucket_name = var.access_log_bucket_name
}

module "s3_user" {
  count      = length(local.users_to_create)
  source     = "./service-s3-bucket-user"
  name       = "${var.name_prefix}${local.users_to_create[count.index]}"
  tags       = var.tags
  bucket_arn = module.s3.bucket_arns[local.users_to_create[count.index]]
  depends_on = [module.s3]
}
```